# Const member function of global variable modifying said variable via global function

Tags: c++, static, constants

The code below

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:

        int x;
        double y;

        A(int x_, double y_) : x(x_), y(y_)
        {
        }

        void display(void) const;
};

class B
{
    public:

        static A staticObject;
};

void A::display(void) const
{
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
    B::staticObject.x = 42;
    B::staticObject.y = 3.5;
    std::cout << x << ' ' << y << std::endl;
}

A B::staticObject(19, 29.3);

int main(void)
{
    B::staticObject.display();
    return 0;
}
```

prints out

```
19 29.3
42 3.5
```

and this makes me wonder:

Is it always safe to let a const member function modify the object it is called from via other means?

Further, is there any worst-case scenario that could be prevented if that member function (here `display`) were not declared as `const`?

Comment: const member functions only apply to the current instance of the object. So when you get a non-const instance of the same object you can call non-const functions there. the const keyword only makes the `this`->pointer a const one.

Comment: What's the context of this design?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is valid and works, because `display()` is `const` but only with respect to its containing class, `A`.  This has no impact on its ability to modify fields accessed another way--in your case via non-const public access to the two fields.

However, this code is terrible and scary.

Answer (score 0):

what do you think as "safe"?

The only assumption you should make of a const member function is that it will not modify the current object it is in (`this` pointer). Constness though is not runtime enforced but during compilation time.

So when you "trick" your compiler with the help of static variables it cannot detect that you are actually accessing the same instance. The `staticObject` in B can also point to another A than the one it's being called from.

To be able to check it would require runtime checks which c++ does not do.